# PHP extension check if key exist

Tags: php, c, php-extension

I am actually to code an extension php (it's wirte in `C`). Any way to know if a key exists in assoc array ? I use `add_assoc_string` but this function erase data if key exist. Currently I do this :

```
array_init(return_value);

add_index_long(return_value, "key1", "value", 1);
add_index_long(return_value, "key2", "value6", 1);
add_index_long(return_value, "key1", "value2", 1);   //here I erase previous key1 by value2
```

Is it possible to check if key1 for example is exists ? Maybe Can I use `hashTable` but I find no example.

**EDIT**

I have finaly find solution, to check if key exist in `zaval array` I do

```
if( zend_hash_exists(Z_ARRVAL_P(return_value), "key", sizeof("key")) ){
    //key exist
}
```

Comment: typo: "ckeck" -> "check"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `zend_hash_index_exists(Z_ARRVAL_P(return_value))` from here [php-src](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/a0502b89a65d24eb191a7c85bcffcf9b91454735/Zend/zend_hash.c).

Functions family starting from `array_` is just wrappers to simplify usage of `zend hash table API`. Look at the source code of `array_init()`. You'll see that under the hood it calls `zend_hash_init()`. So just use appropriate type casting in your code.

More examples how to work with arrays/hast tables in [phpinternalsbook](http://www.phpinternalsbook.com/hashtables/hashtable_api.html).
Also you always can find a lot of useful examples directly in PHP source code [repo](https://github.com/php/php-src). For example for this particular case - [here](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/2d3bf0da449b256abf5d9129f9106a55c17ab053/ext/soap/php_http.c#L984).

**PS:** Also, it looks like this code is not working:

```
...
add_index_long(return_value, "key1", "value", 1);
```

because the real signature is `add_index_long(zval *arg, zend_ulong idx, zend_long n)`, so one cannot use "key1" as `zend_ulong idx` and "value" as `zend_long n` due to type mismatch.

Comment: Right, but I have difficulty to create a multidimensional array with `hashTable`, because `zend_hash_index_exists()` take first parameter is `hashTable` and in my case `return_value` isn't `hashTable` I believe @Ivan Velichko

Comment: Just look at the source code of `array_init()`. You'll see that under the hood it calls `zend_hash_init()`. So just you appropriate type casting in your code. See attached usage example from the `soap` extension.